# How can i check if a JavaScript-Eventhandler has been set?

Tags: javascript, events

I've got a JavaScript-function that sets the "onclick"-event of some HTML-Nodes - even if that "onclick"-event has been set before.

How can i check if that event has already been set, so I can extend my function to set the event only on HTML-Nodes where it has not already been set?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check, like this:

```
if(typeof someNode.onclick == "function") {
   // someNode has an event handler already set for the onclick event...
}
```

By the way, if you are using a library, you should say so - if you are, it might be easier/cleaner and would differ based on which library you are using...

Comment: And, if developer uses something like: button.addEventListener('click', buttonPressed, true); in Mozilla?

Comment: this will not work for event handlers set using attachEvent or addEventListener.

Comment: I am aware of that, but since the OP didn't specify how he is wiring things up, I assumed the DOM 0 method of doing so.

Comment: By the way, this *is* a wiki - feel free to edit my response and add more robust code... :P

Comment: .onclick does not appear to work the same as .mouseenter    :(

Comment: @johnktejik You are mossing an `on`. Make it `.onmouseenter`.

Answer (score 11):

It should be possible to detect event handlers attached using `<element>.addEventListener()` by intercepting calls to the function:

```
var myListOfAddedEvents = [];

var realAddEventListener = HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener;

HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = function(evtType,fn,cap) {
    myListOfAddedEvents.push(
        {on: this, type: evtType, handler: fn, capture: cap}
    );

    return realAddEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Note: That is untested code and may need some work.  I'm *hoping* this same function will be used by all element types, but I could be wrong.  Also it will only work if you can run this bit of code *before* they start adding events.  A copy for attachEvent could be constructed similarly.

Comment: You may want to combine this with Jason Bunting's technique. Because there are two ways to register event handlers, we need to use two different techniques to find them!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" id="foo" name="foo" value="bar" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.getElementById('foo').onclick); //undefined
</script>
```

So what you want to do is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (undefined == document.getElementById('foo').onclick)
    {
        // Add event handler
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this will not work for event handlers set using attachEvent or addEventListener.