# Add a resize event handler only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window-resize

I have a widget that insert a div element in the DOM;
that div needs some js that handles the resize event;

the problem is:

- the widget can be added multiple times on the same page, but I don't wanto to add many identical resize event handlers on the page (one, acting on the specific widget's class will be enough for all the widget instances);
- the page that will embeed the widget can have its own resize event handler, that should not be deleted;

do you have any suggestion about how to implement this?

Comment: [Namespace your widget's event handler](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/09/namespace-your-events), then [check if that event handler exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976343/how-can-i-check-if-a-javascript-eventhandler-has-been-set) before adding a new one.

Comment: The desired outcome is not well define in your question - but if you want to limit a listener to a single instance, but be able to retrieve that instance whenever you would like - you can use a singleton that create a handler on an object and then just passes you back a reference to the object with its handler (and it's props and methods) instead of creating a new one when you call the singleton method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I didn't get most of workflow explained as you didn't provide any html and js but I hope the following works for you:

```
var resized = 0;                     // works as a flag
$( window ).on('resize', function () { 
     if ( resized++ >= 1 ) return;
     // do something here.. 
     console.log('resized once');    // console.log as an example! 
});
```

Good luck.